# jQuery var doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an AJAX registration form:

```
var id = null;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: requestUrl,
    data: $(".defaultRequest").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.response){
            $('div.errormsg').remove();
            if(data.step){
                openStep(data.step);
            }else{
                    openStep('next');

            }
        }else{
            $('div.errormsg').remove();
            $('<div class="errormsg">'+data.message+"</div>").insertBefore(form);
        }
    }
});
```

When a user is successful registered, I want to show him his unique ID, but it stays NULL. How can I solve it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#linkkk').text('Your id is: '+id+'');
</script>
```

Comment: you should put that on the success ( or done) callback. **a**jax is Async. and like @ShadowWizard said , where do you set it? )

Comment: Of course it doesn't change, you don't change it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set id first in success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: requestUrl,
    data: $(".defaultRequest").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.response){
            $('div.errormsg').remove();
            if (data.step) {
                openStep(data.step);
            } else {
                openStep('next');
            }
            $('#linkkk').text('Your id is: ' + data.id);
        } else {
            $('div.errormsg').remove();
            $('<div class="errormsg">'+data.message+"</div>").insertBefore(form);
        }
    }
});
```